# One to many on single row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access database with a contact and phone number table. Each contact can have between 0 and 10 phone numbers. I'm trying to get all of the number for each contact on the same row in order to import as a .csv to another system. I've tried using a pivot but ran into issues since each contact has a varying number of phone numbers.

Comment: Is that SQL Table or HTML Table? You can if you are using MS Access you can get it in a comma separated column. Why do you need it in a <table>?

Comment: sorry... html formatting isn't working correctly... i need it in a access table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on your description, you have a Contacts table like,

`````````````
tbl_Contacts
````````````
contactID   |   contactName
------------+---------------
1           |   Jones
2           |   Jackson
`````````````

A phone record of customers like,

`````````````````
tbl_PhoneRecords
````````````````
phoneID |   contactID   |   contactNumber
--------+---------------+-----------------
1       |   1           |   555-555-5555
2       |   1           |   555-444-7777
3       |   2           |   111-111-1111
`````````````````

And your desired output be like,

```````````
qry_Output
``````````
contactID   |   contactName |   joinedContact
------------+---------------+-------------------------------
1           |   Jones       |   555-555-5555, 555-444-7777
2           |   Jackson     |   111-111-1111
```````````

You might be able to make use of Allen Browne's Code [Concat Related](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html). So your SQL would be something like,

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Contacts.contactID,
    tbl_Contacts.contactName,
    ConcatRelated("contactNumber", "tbl_PhoneRecords", "contactID = " & tbl_Contacts.contactID) As joinedContact
FROM
    tbl_Contacts;
```

Hope this helps !